# What kind of hashing algorithm produces this kind of text?

Tags: hash

8A-25-A5-14-E9-E0-A8-02-0E-91-32-46-44-7E-EE-11

The above one is the hashed text. The original text is "welcome1". Can someone identify the algorithm used here?

Comment: Common hashing would be things like MD5.  I'm guessing as it's 16 bytes long it may be something more like SHA256 but without the key there's no way to know if this is indeed the case.  Where did the text come from?

Comment: MD5 hashing yields a 16-byte (128-bit) result. This is most likely that one.

Comment: But if i select MD5('welcome1') in my database, I'm getting some different value (that doesnt have - ).

Comment: @sathis: The `-` characters are purely to make the hexadecimal representation of the value more human readable by separating apart each byte.  They are not part of the value.

Comment: `echo md5('welcome1')` in PHP doesn't return anything like that value.

Comment: It's none of [these](http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm?text=welcome1) standard functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

according to [this site](http://forum.insidepro.com/viewtopic.php?p=68471), it is apparently an md5 hash of the Unicode representation of "welcome1"

> MD5(Unicode):
>   ...
>   8a25a514e9e0a8020e913246447eee11:welcome1

specifically, it is the UTF-16LE ([UTF16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) Little Endian) representation of the string "welcome1"

```
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] output = md.digest("welcome1".getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
        for(byte out: output){
            System.out.printf("%x", out);
        }
        System.out.println();
```

output:

```
8a25a514e9e0a82e913246447eee11
```

the dashes aren't part of the hash output, only the hexadecimal characters. taking those out and googling the hash will usually turn up the results, especially if it is a common phrase like "welcome1"

This is a great object lesson in why its important to remember character encoding when dealing with hashing algorithms, as they operate on bytes, rather than characters.  hashing "welcome1" in ASCII or UTF8 (or even UTF-16BE) causes wildly different output, because the characters have different underlying byte representations.